# Oracle DB Query Runs in sqlDev but not in Java Program

Tags: java, database, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have been messing with Oracle DB queries that run from my JAVA app. I can successfully get them all to run in SQL Developer. But when I am trying to execute them from my JAVA app I usually get `UpdatadbleResultSet Error/Exception` on certain queries.

Also, sometimes I receive, `ExhaustedResultset`. As I mention at the bottom I will re work the question to break it down(When I get a chance). I keep editing and pretty soon it'll be a book.

Why is this? I cannot seem to pinpoint the problem.

Some queries run successfully such as:

```
SELECT table_name 
FROM all_tables

SELECT column_name, data_length 
FROM all_tab_columns 
WHERE table_name = 'mytable'
```

But when I try and run something like

```
SELECT length(<myColumnName>) 
FROM mytable
```

I get the `updateableResultSetError`

I am running my queries as methods called on button clicks (example below).

```
static void testQuery() {   
 String query = "SELECT blah from blah"
 String length;
 ResultSet rs = db.runQuery(query);
 Length = rs.getString("length(myCol)")
 System.out.println(length);
}
```

I have also tried `while rs.next()`

I can only think that for some reason I am unable to get into each table and I can only pull the "bigger" picture.

***EDIT: Explained DB Connection***

I am connecting using some other jarfiles that have been added to my project.

```
private static IDriver driver = null;
private static Database db = null;
```

I then pass in all my connection credentials in a separate method.

```
private void connectDB(){
driver = new OracleDriver();
db = new Database(driver)   
driver.getPassword;
driver.getetc;
driver.getEtc;
}
```

EDIT:

When I getstacktrace all I am returning is.

```
Ljava.lang.StatckTraceElement;(assortment of random characters).
```

I may not be getting stack traces right so someone can fill me in. After all I am offering a bounty.

Also I will edit this question and break it down again when I have the time.

Comment: It doesn't look like an exception to me, it looks like a reference to an object of type `UpdatableResultSet`

Comment: You shouldn't capitalize your variable names in Java, it makes them look like classes.

Comment: Do you have a stacktrace of the exception?

Comment: BTW: you're calling rs.next() twice: once in the while statement, and once in the loop. Remove the second one.

Comment: Still troubleshooting, and I have found out that I never actually enter the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you're trying to update a query that can't be updated, hence the updateable result error. It seems that whoever is creating your database connection or executing your query is creating an updatable result set.

You can't use certain types of select in an updatable result set: you can't use aggregated functions (such as length, min, max), you can't use select * etc.)

For the full list see [Result Set Limitations and Downgrade Rules](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/java.111/b31224/resltset.htm#CIHEJHJI)

Comment: hmm thats weird, as I said they work perfectly outside the java program. I will look into this.

Comment: sqldeveloper won't try to create an updatable result set, so any select will work in sqldeveloper.

Comment: So is there anyway to bypass this when running a query within the program? Ill reward you the bounty if you know :)

Comment: You can get round it by creating your own connection to the database and subsequently your own preparedstatement and resultset. Then you have complete control.

Answer (score 1):

Try retrieving the value in your select statement via the columnIndex instead of the column name and see if that makes a difference.

Currently, its hard to tell what your `db.runQuery()` does since that code is not posted.

```
String query = "SELECT length(myCol) FROM myTable";
String length;
ResultSet rs = db.runQuery(query);

while (rs.next()) {
 length = rs.getString(1);
 System.out.println(length);
}
```

Comment: I actually tried this earlier too I still receive the same UpdatableResultSet. My DB conn seems to be fine I can run other things. I will try and explain that in question

Comment: You should post the stacktrace of the entire exception that you say you are getting -- `UpdatableResultSet Error/Exception`

Answer (score 1):

I've got an inkling what may be happening here (which would explain why some queries work, and some don't).  Accoring to the jdbc ResultSet [javadocs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getString%28java.lang.String%29), when using the getString() method of the result set, the column label.

> the label for the column specified with the SQL AS clause. 
>   If the SQL AS clause was not specified, then the label is the name of the column

As "length(myCol)" is neither a label nor a column name, it may be that it fell over because of that (but without stacktrace it is difficult to say what your problem actually is).

Try

```
String query = "SELECT length(myCol) AS myCol_len FROM myTable"
ResultSet rs = db.runQuery(query);
String length = rs.getString("myCol_len");
```

Though are you sure, you didn't want:

```
int length = rs.getInt("myCol_len");
```

Alternatively (as written by Kal), you can use the column index to get the data from the result set, which oblivates the need for a SQL AS label:

```
String query = "SELECT length(myCol) FROM myTable"
ResultSet rs = db.runQuery(query);
String length = rs.getString(1);
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment when I get a chance I will try it. I have tried what Kal mentioned and it throws the same error back at me.